# Highcharts. Dynamic labels inside donut chart on mouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, donut-chart

so this is what I'm trying to acomplish:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clnTA.jpg)

What I need is:

- Label inside donut chart changing on mouse over
- Color depending on data
- Styling label to look like the picture

I actually managed to do the mouse over but I can't change the color according to data and place it in the middle

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9cjxb97a/1/

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
        style: {
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
        }
      }
    },
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            var chart = this.series.chart;
            if (!chart.lbl) {
              chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('')
                .attr({
                  padding: 10,
                })
                .css({
                  color: 'red',
                })
                .add();
            }
            chart.lbl
              .show()
              .attr({
                text: this.y + '%'
              });
          }
        }
      },

    },
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
      y: 56.33
    }, {
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 24.03,

    }, {
      name: 'Firefox',
      y: 10.38
    }, {
      name: 'Safari',
      y: 4.77
    }, {
      name: 'Opera',
      y: 0.91
    }, {
      name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
      y: 0.2
    }],
    innerSize: '80%'
  }],

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't you think you should be more concerned about having your chart conmunicate something  useful, than just having it look cool? (Sorry for crashing your party, it's just a pet peeve of mine. Donut and pie charts are useless for pretty much anything, and yet the most used chart, by far. Just because it looks cool)

Comment: The place where it's going already uses pie charts and it's actually the best option to display this kind of data. Because I'm designing for small laptop screens I want to show the data in the most effective way without filling everything with labels and tooltips while looking good.

Btw you can comunicate useful stuff WHILE ALSO looking good. Or else you wouldn't use most of the websites online. Usability and user experience go hand in hand. 

However, I'm intrigued. What would you replace piecharts with?

Sorry if I wrote something wrong, english is not my first language.

Comment: No, no, you didn't write anything wrong. And it's a perfectly valid question, I just think it's a much less important question than the one you should be asking, but seemingly aren't. It's absolutely possible to make something that communicates something useful and looks good. Unfortunately pie charts usually fail at the first and rather crucial part. And fortunately the web isn't completely covered with pie charts yet, but I'm starting to get a bit worried...

Comment: What I'd replace a pie chart with depends entirely on the data and what questions you need answered. But let's take your example here. The only useful question it seems to answer is "which browser has the biggest share?". That question is better answered by a simple sentence: "IE has the biggest share with 56%". It takes up much less space, and you can color it pink and call it sexy if you'd like.

Comment: The pie chart makes any comparison between the individual browser's difficult. If you want to know how much bigger IE's share is compared to the others, you'd have to pull out your measuring band. With a bar chart, however, this would become obvious at a glance.

Comment: @DPF have you any success on this? I really need it

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code to display value in between circle.

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: ''
},
exporting:{
enabled:false
},
tooltip: {
    enabled:false
},
   colors:['red', 'blue', 'green'],
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            }
        }
    },
     series: {
    point: {
        events: {
            mouseOver: function () {
                var chart = this.series.chart;
                if (!chart.lbl) {
                    chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('')
                        .attr({
                            padding: 10,
                        })
                        .css({
                            color: 'red',
                        })
                        .add();
                }
                chart.lbl
                    .show()
                    .attr({
                        text: this.y + '%'
                    });
            }
        }
    },

},
},
 tooltip: {
          borderWidth: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'none',
          headerFormat: '',
          shadow: false,
          style: {
              fontSize: '16px'
          },
          pointFormat: '<span style="font-size:40px;color:black; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span><br><span>50 Kg</span>{point.custom.customParam}',
          positioner: function (labelWidth) {
              return {
                  x: (this.chart.chartWidth - labelWidth) / 2,
                  y: this.chart.plotHeight/2
              };
          }
      },
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        y: 56.33
    }, {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 24.03,

    }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.38
    }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.77
    }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        y: 0.91
    }, {
        name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
        y: 0.2
    }],
    innerSize:'80%'
}],

});
```